# Method cannot be declared public

Tags: swift

I have defined the following class:

```
public class MyService {
  public init() {
  }

  // ERROR: Method cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type
  public func doTask(completion: @escaping (Car?) -> Void) {
  } 

  // No problem here
  public func doSomething(name: String) {
  }
}
```

However, I got compiler error for `doTask(completion:)` but no such error in `doSomething(name:)` as indicated above.

Why? How to get rid of that error?

Comment: Remove the 't' from `@escapting`

Comment: That's just a typo in question, not the cause of error.

Comment: Please paste *your actual code* since there is nothing wrong with what you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your actual signature (which I'm guessing is not the one you've pasted) is using a type that's internal to the file or module. It makes no sense to have a function that's `public`, but that you need to provide a private type to call - how could anyone call it?

Either make the used types public as well, or make the function non-public.